# How to open a PopUp Window, if an "if-statement" is true?

Tags: android, if-statement, popup

I am a complete noob and need your help:

I created a simple counter, that counts how often you clicked a button.
Now comes the difficult part.
I want a PopUp Window to pop up, if the counter reached the number 10.

I have no clue how to do that, and hope you can give me some hints! :3

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ALERT DIALOGS](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html)

for this purpose in android to achieve what you want :)

Answer (score 0):

Use DialogFragment or DialogManager.

Read here more about Dialogs.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html

Answer (score 0):

```
if (stateIsTrue) {
        AlertDialog.Builder alBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        alBuilder.setMessage("your message here");
        alBuilder.setPositiveButton("yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                // do your stuff 
            }
        }).setNegativeButton("no", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                dialogInterface.dismiss();
            }
        }).show();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it seems something is still missing.
The Dialog unfortunately doesn´t show up.
Did if forget something? :(